# Arraylist filter and send other arraylist

Tags: java, list, algorithm, oop, arraylist

Model class

```
class Person {
    private String id;
    private String name;
    private int age;

    // Constructor
    public Person(String id,String name, int age) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
    }

    // Getter ve Setter metotları
    public String getID() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setID(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public int getAge() {
        return age;
    }

    public void setAge(int age) {
        this.age = age;
    }
}
```

Here is main:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList<Person> personList = new ArrayList<>();

        personList.add(new Person("1","John", 25));
        personList.add(new Person("2","Alice", 30));
        personList.add(new Person("3","Bob", 28));
}
```

I want to filter like this - `filterednewArraylist = (id =1 in person list)`.

I tried collections and stream filter, but it's not working.

Answer (score 0):

As you noted, streaming and filtering is the way to go:

```java
List<Person> filteredList =
    personList.stream()
              .filter(p -> p.getID().equals("1"))
              .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

If you absolutely must have an `ArrayList` and not any old list (which is probably not a great idea, see e.g. [What does it mean to "program to an interface"?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/383947/2422776)), you can use `toCollection` instead of `toList`:

```java
ArrayList<Person> filteredArrayList =
    personList.stream()
              .filter(p -> p.getID().equals("1"))
              .collect(Collectors.toCollection(ArrayList::new));
```

Comment: Just to note, it's possible to program to an interface, while making sure the stream returns an ArrayList - `List<Person> filteredArrayList = personList.stream().filter(...).collect(Collectors.toCollection(ArrayList::new));`

Comment: @Chaosfire true, but IMHO that would probably be a codesmell. If your code accepts any `List` but implicitly assumes the behavior of an `ArrayList` (e.g., `get(int)` being an O(1) operation), you're asking for trouble. In such a case, why not make these assumptions explicit and requiring an `ArrayList`?

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned, you also can go with Collections. This way is more clearer, easier and shorter.

```
// Sorting based on ID
Collections.sort(personList, Comparator.comparing(Person::getID));
```

Answer (score 0):

To filter the personList to get a new ArrayList containing only the persons with an ID of "1", you can use Java streams and the filter method.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class Main {
 public static void main(String[] args) {
    ArrayList<Person> personList = new ArrayList<>();

    personList.add(new Person("1","John", 25));
    personList.add(new Person("2","Alice", 30));
    personList.add(new Person("3","Bob", 28));

    // Filter persons with ID "1"
    List<Person> filteredPersonList = personList.stream()
            .filter(person -> person.getID().equals("1"))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());

    // Print the filtered persons
    for (Person person : filteredPersonList) {
        System.out.println("ID: " + person.getID() + ", Name: " + person.getName() + ", Age: " + person.getAge());
    }
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The proper way to filter a `List` in modern Java (JDK 17/21) is the following:

```java
import java.util.List;

public class FilterById {
    record Person(String id, String name, int age) {}

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Person> people = List.of(
                new Person("1", "John", 25),
                new Person("2", "Alice", 30),
                new Person("3", "Bob", 28)
        );

        List<Person> peopleWithAnIdOfOne = people.stream()
                .filter(p -> p.id.equals("1"))
                .toList();

        System.out.println(peopleWithAnIdOfOne); // [Person[id=1, name=John, age=25]]
    }
}
```

This is a functional approach. The filtered result is an immutable copy of the original list. I simplified this with the use of:

- a `Person` `record` (JDK 14)
- an immutable input list ~ `List.of` (JDK 9)
- an immutable output list ~ `Stream::toList` (JDK 16)

#### Mutability

We do not even have to explicitly use `ArrayList` at all. Unless you need to modify the result, you should pass the resulting collection to a new `ArrayList`.

```java
List<Person> filteredPeople = new ArrayList<>(peopleWithAnIdOfOne); // Mutable list
```

---

### Advanced usage

If you want to combine an accessor/mapper and a predicate, you could try the following.

**Note:** This will not work with a record, because `Person::age` cannot be referenced from a static context. You will need a method accessor like `Person::getAge`.

```java
import lombok.Value;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.function.Function;
import java.util.function.Predicate;

public class FilterById {
    @Value
    static class Person {
        String id, name;
        int age;
    }

    // As a predicate functional interface
    private static final Predicate<Integer> isOlderThan25 = age -> age > 25;

    // As a static method
    private static boolean isOlderThan25(int age) {
        return age > 25;
    }

    private static final List<Person> people = List.of(
            new Person("1", "John", 25),
            new Person("2", "Alice", 30),
            new Person("3", "Bob", 28)
    );

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        {
            // Predicate functional interface
            List<Person> peopleOlderThan25 = people.stream()
                    .filter(comparator(Person::getAge, FilterById::isOlderThan25))
                    .toList();
            System.out.println(peopleOlderThan25);
        }

        {
            // Static method
            List<Person> peopleOlderThan25 = people.stream()
                    .filter(comparator(Person::getAge, isOlderThan25))
                    .toList();
            System.out.println(peopleOlderThan25);
        }
    }

    // Generic utility method that accepts a mapper and a predicate
    public static <T, R> Predicate<T> comparator(Function<T, R> mapper, Predicate<R> predicate) {
        return item -> predicate.test(mapper.apply(item));
    }
}
```